# Reading integers from text files

Tags: c#

I have a file 'HighScores.txt' which contains data such as

```
0
12
76
90
54
```

I would like to add this text file into an array of integers as I would like to sort this, I'm just having trouble looping through each item and converting it from a string to an int.

```
string path = "score.txt";
int[] HighScores;

if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
        tw.Close();
    }
    else if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        //READ FROM TEXT FILE


    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use LINQ:

```
int[] highScores = File
    .ReadAllText("score.txt")
    .Split(' ')
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Sir can you please suggest for a case, when i have one line with following text `Pankaj 1212 dc3e 12 45r 12`. The code above mentioned till split gives mixed array of int and numeric values. How can i extract only numeric ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `File.ReadLines` + Linq:

```
int[] orderedNumbers = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(line => line.Trim().TryGetInt())
    .Where(nullableInteger => nullableInteger.HasValue)
    .Select(nullableInteger => nullableInteger.Value)
    .OrderByDescending(integer => integer)
    .ToArray();
```

This is the extension method which i'm using to detect if a string can be parsed to an `int`:

```
public static int? TryGetInt(this string item)
{
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}
```